# Can another application launch popup when user is browsing

Tags: android

My company has a need to display a warning popup in the browser if employee visits URLs with their Android phone that are in the deemed "dangerous". Not my idea and I don't particularly agree but my job is to research for solution.

I think there's two major questions I would appreciate answer for:
1) Is there a way to monitor URLs visited (1-2sec polling is probably acceptable)?
2) Can background app initiate popup in the browser or inject into DOM?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer for 1 is no and the answer for 2 is yes.

Comment: The 'browser".. is this a custom browser of the Android browser?

Comment: @Martijn Van Mierloo: Android browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a custom browser, an Activity with a WebView, you will get the URLs loaded and do some action based on that.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {         
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (isDangerous(url)) {
            //show some dialog
        }               
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: So this would work only if I create custom browser and not with Android stock browser?

Comment: Yes, stock browser this is not possible.